# Flutter : The getter was called on null (JSON API call)

Tags: flutter, dart, jsonapi-serialize

I've a problem where I know where something went wrong but I can't figure how to solve it.
I'm new to the Flutter developpement and I'm trying to create an application.
For this application, I need to call an API that return data, but based on what I ask i can have different returns.

Here are two examples :

```
{
  "name": "Luken",
  "race": "Blood Elf",
  "class": "Death Knight",
  "active_spec_name": "Blood",
  "active_spec_role": "TANK",
  "gender": "male",
  "faction": "horde",
  "achievement_points": 5145,
  "honorable_kills": 0,
  "thumbnail_url": "https://render-eu.worldofwarcraft.com/character/ysondre/200/100426440-avatar.jpg?alt=wow/static/images/2d/avatar/10-0.jpg",
  "region": "eu",
  "realm": "Ysondre",
  "profile_url": "https://raider.io/characters/eu/ysondre/Luken",
  "profile_banner": "hordebanner1",
  "guild": null
}
```

Second API return :

```
{
  "name": "Rakhalar",
  "race": "Zandalari Troll",
  "class": "Druid",
  "active_spec_name": "Guardian",
  "active_spec_role": "TANK",
  "gender": "male",
  "faction": "horde",
  "achievement_points": 5525,
  "honorable_kills": 0,
  "thumbnail_url": "https://render-eu.worldofwarcraft.com/character/illidan/213/142815957-avatar.jpg?alt=wow/static/images/2d/avatar/31-0.jpg",
  "region": "eu",
  "realm": "Illidan",
  "profile_url": "https://raider.io/characters/eu/illidan/Rakhalar",
  "profile_banner": "hordebanner1",
  "guild": {
    "name": "Gueule de Bois",
    "realm": "Illidan"
  }
```

The main difference between the two returns is the guild key : It **can** be null. 
I don't know how to handle it, as it result an error when I'm trying to call for the *name* or *realm* value when the character (it's basically information for WoW characters that return the API).

The Class i'm using to serialize the JSON is the following :

```
class Guild {
  String name;
  String realm;

  Guild({
    this.name,
    this.realm,
  });

  factory Guild.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Guild(
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        realm: json["realm"] == null ? null : json["realm"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "realm": realm == null ? null : realm,
      };
}
```

And there's the UI part (in case it's something to do in the view side, but I really don't think so.)

```
class CharacterDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final CharacterDetailArguments args;

  CharacterDetailPage({this.args});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Detail page for ${args.name}"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<CharacterDetailApi>(
          future: getCharacterDetails(args.name, args.realm, args.region),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? Container(
                        child: 
                          Container(
                            height: 125,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(snapshot.data.name, ),
                                Text("<" + snapshot.data.guild.name + ">",),
                                Text(snapshot.data.guild.realm,),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                  )
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm sure it's a basic issue but I didn't find any relevant information for it yet :(

**Edit : There's the code that work, using anonymous function :**

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(snapshot.data.name,),
    if (snapshot.data.guild != null)
      Text("<" + snapshot.data.guild.name +">",),
    if (snapshot.data.guild != null)
      Text(snapshot.data.guild.realm,),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this code

```
Text("<" + snapshot.data.guild.name + ">",),
Text(snapshot.data.guild.realm,),
```

to this :

```
if (snapshot.data.guild != null) {
   Text("<" + snapshot.data.guild.name + ">"),
   Text(snapshot.data.guild.realm),
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the syntax wasn't good. I had to use an immediate anonymous function for each of my test. I'll update the question as it's solved now. Thanks !

Comment: I think it would have been easier if you had parsed your Json into a character class which has guild as one of it's variables.

Comment: In fact, that's what I did (using quicktype) :
`
factory CharacterDetailApi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      CharacterDetailApi(
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        race: json["race"] == null ? null : json["race"],
        [a lot of other lines]
        guild: json["guild"] == null ? null : Guild.fromJson(json["guild"]),
      );
`

Is there anything to do here ?

Comment: That doesn't work then. It's prolly because the UI tries to call for a non existing key/values when the api returns **null** instead of *guilld name* and *guild realm*

Comment: @Psykotik Why is your edit unsatisfactory ? i thought it works, what do you want to change ?

Comment: I was used to create a widget out of my UI code when everything works, to clean up the code into chunks instead of big file but now as i need to check for a node instead of a final value, i can't pass through my widget the information and test it (or can't find a way to do so atm)